# node.js child_process.send utf-8 char issue

Tags: node.js

today i upgrade my node.exe to the latest version:0.10.0.But found a strange issue :can't send chinese char,the code is:

master.js:

```
//master.js
var cp = require('child_process');

var n = cp.fork(__dirname + '/sub.js');

n.on('message', function(m) {
console.log('PARENT got message:', m);
});

n.send('中文');
```

and:

```
//sub.js
process.on('message', function(m) {
console.log('CHILD got message:', m);
});

process.send({ foo: 'bar' });
```

when run master.js,an error occured:

undefined:1
"d8-f"
     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:335:28)

does anyone can give some advise？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce it.

Although it seems to be a bug (since it works okay in Node 0.8), this works as a fix:

```
// master.js
...
n.send(new Buffer('中文'));

// sub.js
process.on('message', function(m) {
  console.log('CHILD got message:', new Buffer(m).toString());
});
....
```

Comment: Yep, definitely a bug. I filed an issue: https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/4999

Comment: this works,thanks.I have decided to rollback my node.js version to 0.8.22 and wait the bug be fixed.